# How do I get preceding and following lines when a specific string is contained in a line? (Python and deque())

Tags: python, regex, text, deque

Sample of text file in a directory:

```
text1 = "
SomethingAAA SomethingAAA SomethingAAA SomethingAAA 
SomethingBBB SomethingBBB SomethingBBB SomethingBBB 
SomethingCCC SomethingCCC SomethingCCC SomethingCCC 
SomethingDDD SomethingDDD SomethingDDD SomethingDDD 
BlahBlah SomethingXXX BlahBlah BlahBlah BlahBlah BlahBlah 
SomethingEEE SomethingEEE SomethingEEE SomethingEEE 
SomethingFFF SomethingFFF SomethingFFF SomethingFFF 
SomethingGGG SomethingGGG SomethingGGG SomethingGGG 
BlahBlah BlahBlah BlahBlah SomethingYYY BlahBlah
SomethingGGG SomethingGGG SomethingGGG SomethingGGG 
"
```

I have two regex patterns I use to identify the strings in the texts:

```
pattern1 = re.compile(r'\w+XXX')
pattern2 = re.compile(r'\w+YYY')
```

The goal is to save the lines containing the patterns plus the preceding line and following line in a new text file.

So the desired output would be:

```
newtext = "
SomethingDDD SomethingDDD SomethingDDD SomethingDDD 
BlahBlah SomethingXXX BlahBlah BlahBlah BlahBlah BlahBlah 
SomethingEEE SomethingEEE SomethingEEE SomethingEEE 

SomethingGGG SomethingGGG SomethingGGG SomethingGGG 
BlahBlah BlahBlah BlahBlah SomethingYYY BlahBlah
SomethingGGG SomethingGGG SomethingGGG SomethingGGG 
"
```

What I'm doing now is:

```
relevant piece of code:

previous_line = deque()
for text_doc in text_docs:

    with open(text_doc,'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            nextline = next(f).strip()
            prev_line.appendleft(line)
            with open(
                output, "a"                
            ) as Results:
                 if re.search(pattern1, line):
                    previous_line = "".join(previous_line.popleft())
                    found_pattern1 = previous_line + line + nextline
                    Results.write(f"\n\nInstance of pattern1: \n{found_pattern1}\n\n")
                elif re.search(pattern2, line):                    
                    previous_line = "".join(previous_line.popleft())
                    found_pattern2 = previous_line + line + nextline
                    Results.write(f"\n\nInstance of pattern2: \n{found_pattern2}\n\n")
  
            prev_line.clear()
```

what I'm getting, however, is:

```
newtext = "
BlahBlah SomethingXXX BlahBlah BlahBlah BlahBlah BlahBlah 
BlahBlah SomethingXXX BlahBlah BlahBlah BlahBlah BlahBlah 
SomethingEEE SomethingEEE SomethingEEE SomethingEEE 

BlahBlah BlahBlah BlahBlah SomethingYYY BlahBlah
BlahBlah BlahBlah BlahBlah SomethingYYY BlahBlah
SomethingGGG SomethingGGG SomethingGGG SomethingGGG"
```

What is it that I'm doing wrong and what do I have to change to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 1):

You can join `pattern1` and `pattern2` with an alternation pattern and include the preceding and following lines with `(?:.*\n)?`, and use `re.findall` to find all matches:

```
patterns = [r'\w+XXX', r'\w+YYY']
new_text = '\n'.join(re.findall(rf"(?:.*\n)?(?:.*(?:{'|'.join(patterns)}).*\n)+(?:.*\n)?", text1))
```

Demo: https://replit.com/@blhsing/RosybrownGargantuanAnalysts

Comment: Thanks @blhsing. This works when the input is a string but it doesn't work for my purposes because I need to loop through different text files. Try doing this with specific files in a directory and do:

for file in folderX:
    with open(file, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
       if re.findall(rf"(?:.*\n)?(?:.*(?:{'|'.join(patterns)}).*\n)+(?:.*\n)?", line):

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a solution. Here it is in case it can help somebody:

```
output_lines = deque(maxlen=3)
for text_doc in text_docs:
    print(text_doc)
    with open(text_doc, 'r') as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
        for i, line in enumerate(lines):  
            if re.search(Pattern1, line) or re.search(Pattern2, line):
                try:
                    output_lines.extend([lines[i-1], line, lines[i+1]])
                except StopIteration:
                    pass #EOF

                with open(
                    output.txt, "a"                
                ) as Results:
                    complete_output = ''.join(output_lines)
                    Results.writelines('============================================\n')
                    Results.writelines(f"\nLines with pattern: \n{complete_output}\n\n")
                    Results.writelines('============================================\n')
```

Or an alternative that doesn't require the use of deque():

```
output_lines = []
for text_doc in text_docs:
    print(text_doc)
    with open(text_doc, 'r') as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
        for i, line in enumerate(lines):  
            if re.search(Pattern1, line) or re.search(Pattern2, line):
                try:
                    output_lines.append(lines[i-1])
                    output_lines.append(line)
                    output_lines.append(lines[i+1])
                except StopIteration:
                    pass #EOF

                with open(
                    output.txt, "a"                
                ) as Results:
                    complete_output = ''.join(output_lines)
                    Results.writelines('============================================\n')
                    Results.writelines(f"\nLines with pattern: \n{complete_output}\n\n")
                    Results.writelines('============================================\n')
                output_lines = []
```